# is there any code of this question in python to print those given numbers and the question instruction is down blow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Given the following numbers separated by commas(",")

numbers="23,67,78,12,5,600,23,67,23,75"

Arrange them in descending order

Show your answer as a string and use printer() function

Comment: Hi Aravatt, can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should learn how to search the internet for help. Google your question before asking other people

Comment: Split, sort as array, join back.

Comment: yeah  this  question was taken me 1 and half hour, so i  got in one way in  descending order but it was not a string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick for you:

```
numbers = "23,67,78,12,5,600,23,67,23,75"

list = numbers.split(",") #Splitting the commas

list.sort(key=int, reverse=True) #sorting it into descending order

print(", ".join(list)) #Printing it out as a string
```

`reverse=True` prints out it in descending order, as seen below:

[image]

Without that or with `reverse=False` you will get them in ascending order:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the output is still an integer, the output must be string

Comment: how exactly are you wanting the input to look like? If you print it out as a string it still looks the same, I'm confused.